# How to use mediainfo dll in java application?

Tags: java, mediainfo

How to use mediainfo dll in java application?
I want to use mediainfo dll in java project.

Comment: I thought it came with JNI examples...any way, you could try looking at something like [ MediaInfoDLL.JNA.java](https://github.com/cehoffman/mkm4v/blob/master/ext/mediainfo/MediaInfoLib/Source/MediaInfoDLL/MediaInfoDLL.JNA.java)

Comment: If you download the source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/files/source/libmediainfo/0.7.63/) (I used the all inclusive package), you can find Java based examples in the projects directory